# Programmatically fetching contacts from Yahoo! Address Book

Tags: python, yahoo

Is there a way to programmatically  log into Yahoo!, providing email id and password as inputs, and fetch the user's contacts?

I've achieved the same thing with Gmail, thanks to the its ClientLogin interface.

Yahoo Address book API provides BBAuth, which requires the user to be redirected to Yahoo login page. But I'm looking for a way to authenticate the user with Yahoo without the redirection. The way Ning.com handles it.

Code samples in Python will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Link for Gdata ClientLogin: 
http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/docs/1.0/developers_guide_python.html#client_login

Comment: Do you want Yahoo to change their API and take out the redirect?  Perhaps you should post this question to them.  Or are you looking to use urllib2 to cope with the redirect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a python script that solves my problem

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ContactGrabber/0.1

It's not complete though, fetches only a portion of the address book.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into the [Contacts API](http://developer.yahoo.com/social/rest_api_guide/contact_api.html) provided by Yahoo!

Comment: thanks @contagious.Although the documentation there is not clear. How do you get the GUID for a user?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this
http://developer.yahoo.com/social/contacts/