# How can access the list of contacts of yahoo mail through Java program?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Taking contact list from hotmail gmail yahoo in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397933/taking-contact-list-from-hotmail-gmail-yahoo-in-java)

I want to access the list of all contact of yahoo mail id through java program. 
if you have any idea then plz give me your suggestion for that.

thanks

Shailendra singh

Comment: There is a similar question already, but the accepted answer was to use the Yahoo! Address Book API, which is now depreciated in favour of the Yahoo! Contacts API.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/909508/programmatically-fetching-contacts-from-yahoo-address-book

Answer (score 0):

You want the [Yahoo! Contacts API](http://developer.yahoo.com/social/contacts/) for that.  Yahoo don't provide specific Java examples for the Contacts API, but they have a [Java Developer Center](http://developer.yahoo.com/java/) with lots of Java/Yahoo resources.